# Отправка на печать Си C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, печать

Здравствуйте. Не могу вывести на печать обычный текст из нескольких символов.
Использую вот эту функцию https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162959(v=vs.85).aspx

Вот сам код консольного приложения, который запускает функцию:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPTSTR printerName = (LPTSTR)_T("XP-58");
    CString str = "la-la-la";
    LPBYTE pByte = new BYTE[str.GetLength() + 1];
    memcpy(pByte, (VOID*)LPCTSTR(str), str.GetLength());
    DWORD count = 7;
    BOOL result = RawDataToPrinter(printerName, pByte, count);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Имя принтера указано верно, он открывается, потому что в консоли после завершения работы написана цифра 1.

Проблема заключается в том, что документ добавляется в очередь на печать, и сразу удаляется оттуда, как будто уже распечатался, хотя принтер вообще ничего не напечатал.

Есть подозрения, что что-то с портом принтера, он подключен к USB002. Когда я отправляю на печать что-нибудь из блокнота, то в очереди на печать видно, что прописан порт USB002, но через мою программу задание в очереди на печать без порта.

Как задать принтеру порт, при открытии?
Или, может быть, у меня в другом проблема?

Comment: У вас UNICODE объявлен? А то у вас везде "T", а в коде выделяете `new BYTE` почему-то.

Comment: Нет. Подскажите пожалуйста как объявить? Я делал точку останова после записи байтов на принтер, в переменных написано что было записано 7 байт.

Comment: Еще у меня подозрения что нужно где то порт принтера указать. Его можно как нибудь указать для функции OpenPrinter? Просто когда я делаю печать из какой нибудь программы, например из блокнота. то в очереди для печати в документе написан порт USB002, а когда отсылаю на печать через свою программу, то порт не написан. И документ добавляется в очередь и сразу же удаляется.

Answer (score 3):

Долго думал над этим вопросом.

Непонятно, откуда вы берете значение `printerName` "XP-58". Скорее всего, такого принтера не находится, и задание просто отправляется в стандартный виртуальный принтер, который является аналогом /dev/null или печати в файл.

Скорее всего, это значение неверно, и нужно сначала вызвать [`EnumPrinters()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx) и найти правильное имя для принтера/сервера печати.

P.S. Это просто теория, и далеко не факт что она сработает.

Comment: Название принтера взял из Панели управления - Устройства и принтеры. Сейчас попробую проЕнумеровать принтеры)) Спасибо

Comment: Я просто видел примеры кода, как люди пишут название модели принтера - так как он называется в панели управления. Например "Deskjet D2300"

Comment: Попробовал вывести названия принтеров, у одного из них название X и порт U. Я так понял что название и порт вывелись не полностью, а только по первому символу, то есть XP-58 и USB002. Получается название указал верно. Подскажите, может все же можно как нибудь порт для принтера указать в функции OpenPrinter?